# How to delete all records in a table using SubSonic 3

Tags: activerecord, subsonic, subsonic3, delete-record

I'm trying to delete all the records from a table using this approach:

```
new Delete<Contact>().Execute();
```

This statement fails with a `NullReferenceException` in `BuildDeleteStatement` method at line:

```
sb.Append(query.FromTables[0].QualifiedName);
```

Because, although FromTables has one entry, it is set to null. I also tried this but it doesn't worked either:

```
var provider = ProviderFactory.GetProvider("MonitorData");
new Delete<Contact>(provider).Execute();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the repo DeleteMany method:

```
SubSonicRepository<Contact> repo = new SubSonicRepository<Contact>(new YourDB());
repo.DeleteMany(contact => true);
```

The lambda I'm using is just to ensure all records are selected.