# Delete using 2 tables join and wheres

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic3, delete-record

I have 2 tables,

```
POST (idpost, user, text)
COMMENT (idcomment, idpost, text)
```

I want to delete all comments with post that have a user like "usertest",

```
delete from COMMENT c join POST p on c.idpost = p.idpost
where p.user like 'usertest'
```

How do I do this in subsonic 3?

I tried something like this, but, off course, it doesn't work,

```
COMMENT.Delete(x => x.POST.where(y => y.user == "usertest"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a subsonic programmer, but there is another article in StackOverflow about deleting all records in a table:

[How to delete all records in a table using SubSonic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333171/how-to-delete-all-records-in-a-table-using-subsonic-3)

It seemed like this might be a good starting place, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the following:

```
IQueryable<Person> query = from comments in Comment.All()
                           join posts in Post.All()
                             on posts.idpost equals comment.idpost
                           select comments;

Comment.GetRepo().Delete(query.ToList());
```